# select box border dosen't load colour correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm building a signup system. I have 3 select boxes of day month and year for a birthdate.
I'm trying to do so when you submit the information, it'll check if the user chooses a full date and it also checks if the user is older than 13. if he's younger, or if he chooses only a day and month, but not a year for example, then the select box's border will become red. The problem is that when I load the page even for the first time, the borders of the day and year boxes are already red. here's the code. what's the problem?

```
<?php
$currentDate = (null);
$date = (null);
$usersday = (null);
$usersyear = (null); 
$usersmonth = (null);
$diff = (null);
$users_age = (null);
if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    $usersday = (int)$_POST['day']; 
    $usersyear = (int)$_POST['year']; 
    $usersmonth = (int)$_POST['month'];
    $date = new DateTime("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
    $today = new DateTime('today');
    $diff = $today->diff($date);
    $users_age = $diff->format('%y');
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
if (($usersday !== null) || ($usersmonth !== null) || ($usersyear !== null) || ($users_age < 
13)) {
        $date = (null);
        echo
        "#month {
        border-color: #ff0000;
        }";
        echo
        "#day {
        border-color: #ff0000;
        }";
        echo
        "#year {
        border-color: #ff0000;
        }";
        echo
        ".birthday-label {
        color: #ff0000;
        }";
    }
    ?>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group">
            <select id="day" name="day" autocomplete="off" class="select-box">
                <option hidden selected selected value="0" >Day</option>
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                <select id="month" name="month" autocomplete="off" class="select-box">
                <option hidden selected value="0" >Month</option>
                <option id="jan" value="1">Jan</option>
                <option id="feb" value="2">Feb</option>
                <option id="mar" value="3">Mar</option>
                <option id="apr" value="4">Apr</option>
                <option id="may" value="5">May</option>
                <option id="jun" value="6">Jun</option>
                <option id="jul" value="7">Jul</option>
                <option id="aug" value="8">Aug</option>
                <option id="sep" value="9">Sep</option>
                <option id="oct" value="10">Oct</option>
                <option id="nov" value="11">Nov</option>
                <option id="dec" value="12">Dec</option>
            </select>
            <select id="year" name="year" autocomplete="off" class="select-box">
                <option hidden selected value="0" >Year</option>
                <?php
                for ($i = 2023; $i >= 1900; $i--) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: a picture of the page when I load it]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the PHP code responsible for setting the border colors is executed when the page loads, and since your variables like $usersday and $usersyear are initially set to null, the conditions for setting the border color are met right away.

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering, second, but the borders should be red only if it's not null.  there is an exclamation mark. why then it's red if i defined it as null? nad why is it the day and year, but not month?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should only apply the red border color when the form is submitted and the conditions are met. You can do this by moving the CSS code that sets the border color inside the conditional block that checks for the form submission. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<?php
$currentDate = null;
$date = null;
$usersday = null;
$usersyear = null; 
$usersmonth = null;
$diff = null;
$users_age = null;

if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
$usersday = (int)$_POST['day']; 
$usersyear = (int)$_POST['year']; 
$usersmonth = (int)$_POST['month'];
$date = new DateTime("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
$today = new DateTime('today');
$diff = $today->diff($date);
$users_age = $diff->format('%y');

if ($usersday !== null || $usersmonth !== null || $usersyear !== null || 
    $users_age < 13) {
        echo "
        #month, #day, #year {
            border-color: #ff0000;
        }
        .birthday-label {
            color: #ff0000;
        }";
    }
}
?>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <select id="day" name="day" autocomplete="off" class="select-box">
            <option hidden selected selected value="0" >Day</option>
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select id="month" name="month" autocomplete="off" class="select- 
box">
            <option hidden selected value="0" >Month</option>
            <!-- Rest of your month options -->
        </select>
        <select id="year" name="year" autocomplete="off" class="select- 
box">
            <option hidden selected value="0" >Year</option>
            <!-- Rest of your year options -->
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now that's a ChatGPT answer...

Answer (score 0):

With this code, the red borders and styles will only be applied after you submit the form and there's an issue with the date you entered. When you first load the page, everything will look normal, without any red borders

```
<?php
$currentDate = null;
$date = null;
$usersday = null;
$usersyear = null; 
$usersmonth = null;
$diff = null;
$users_age = null;

// Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    $usersday = (int)$_POST['day']; 
    $usersyear = (int)$_POST['year']; 
    $usersmonth = (int)$_POST['month'];

    // Check if a full date has been selected
    if ($usersday !== 0 && $usersmonth !== 0 && $usersyear !== 0) {
        $date = new DateTime("$usersyear-$usersmonth-$usersday");
        $today = new DateTime('today');
        $diff = $today->diff($date);
        $users_age = $diff->format('%y');
    }
}

// Check if there are issues with the user's input and apply red border styles
if ((!isset($_POST['submit-button'])) || ($usersday === 0 && $usersmonth !== 0) || ($usersyear === 0 && $usersmonth !== 0) || $users_age < 13) {
    echo <<<CSS
        <style>
            #day, #year {
                border-color: #ff0000;
            }
            .birthday-label {
                color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>
    CSS;
}
?>
```

Comment: The issue happens because the code to check for valid date input wasn't set up correctly. The code was mistakenly applying red borders when it shouldn't. To fix this, we need to make sure the red borders only appear when there's a problem with what the user entered.

Comment: Think of it like this: Imagine you're filling out a form, and you haven't submitted it yet. Everything should look normal. Only after you submit the form should it check if there are any issues with the date you provided and, if so, display those red borders.